# jQuery Creating/Adding to multidimensional array from large form

Tags: jquery, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I'm not understanding how jQuery handles multidimensional arrays.

I have a very large form inside a wizard plugin. On one step there could be up to 10 tabs, within each of those tabs could be several dozen text inputs. I'm trying to to use .each to gather all text inputs and arrange them in a multidimensional array.

```
var ItemsArray = [];
var ItemGroup = [];
$('.GroupOfTabs').each(function() { //for each tab
  var TabName = $(this).val();

  //for each input inside each tab
  $('#step-3 tr[room='+TabName+'][object=item]').each(function() { 
    var value1 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value1]).val();
    var value2 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value2]).val();
    var value3 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value3]).val();
    var value4 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value4]).val();

    ItemGroup.push( {value1, value2}, {value3, value4} );   
    ItemsArray[TabName].push(ItemGroup);
  });
});
```

HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="GroupOfTabs" value="tab1">
  <table>
    <tr room="tab1" object=item>
      <td><input tab=tab1 other=value1></td>
      <td><input tab=tab1 other=value2></td>
      <td><input tab=tab1 other=value3></td>
      <td><input tab=tab1 other=value4></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

so on for many tabs and many more inputs.

So what I was hoping for was a nice organized multidimensional array like so:

```
ItemsArray
{
     Tab1 : { value1 : value2 }, {value3 : value4}
     Tab2 : { value1 : value2 }, {value3 : value4}
     Tab3 : { value1 : value2 }, {value3 : value4}
}

//An easier way for me to articulate the array structure is php style:

(ItemsArray => array( Tab1 => array(value1 => value2, value3 => value4),
               array( Tab2 => array(value1 => value2, value3 => value4),
               array( Tab3 => array(value1 => value2, value3 => value4))
```

I'm not even going to bother showing what the actual output I get is... safe to assume its an awful mess. Its not even returning all text inputs, just the first from each tab.

Proper way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to also see some sample HTML. In the meantime, where is `RoomName` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your variables as arrays, but based on your hoped-for output it looks like you really want to use objects. We don't know much about your document structure, so the following is just a guess based on what you were trying to do.

(I'm assuming that you are getting the correct values in value1-value4.)

```
var ItemsArray = {}; $('.GroupOfTabs').each(function() { //for each tab   var TabName = $(this).val();

  //for each input inside each tab   $('#step-3 tr[room='+TabName+'][object=item]').each(function() { 
    var value1 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value1]').val();
    var value2 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value2]').val();
    var value3 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value3]').val();
    var value4 = $('#step-3 input[tab='+TabName+'][other=value4]').val();

    ItemsArray[TabName] = [ { value1 : value2 } , { value3 : value4 } ];   }); });
```

The structure of `ItemsArray` doesn't really make much sense to me out of context like this. Assuming your sample output is actually what you wanted I think this should work.